# Технология позиционирования по wi-fi сетям

Tags: android, wifi, геолокация

Изучаю wi-fi технологию позиционирования и хочу понять чем отличаются либо похожи  механизмы wi-fi позиционирования от других технологии позиционирования (GSM , GPS)

1. Кординаты wi-fi router-a фиксированы как в случае GSM позиционировании кординаты BTS?
2. Кординаты wi-fi динамичны как в случае  GPS кординаты спутников?
3. Или сам по себе wi-fi устройство  не имеет кординаты и с помощью  wi-fi могут позиционировать лишь  те  компании  геолокационных услуг которые имеют базу (уже  собранную карту wi-fi router-ов, которые создали с помощью  сопоставления wi-fi устройств с местоположением, которые получили с помощью GPS)?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №3

По улицам ездят машинки и потихоньку собирают SSID/MAC адреса работающих роутеров, вбивают их координаты в БД, дальше уже дело техники как организовать позиционирование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]